# SOCI Undefined Reference Error During Compilation

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm trying to get soci working, and am basing my code on their documentation [here](http://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/basics.html). I'm getting an error that I can't decipher.

My code:

```
// relevant imports
using namespace soci;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string dbName = "mysql";
    string options = "dbname=db user=root password=abc";
    try {
        session sql(dbName, options); // this is line 22
    } catch (exception e) {
        printf("%s", e.what());
    }
    printf("working");
    return 0;
}
```

The error:

```
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `main':
/home/kevin/Dropbox/bamboo/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to
`soci::session::session(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/home/kevin/Dropbox/bamboo/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to `soci::session::~session()'
```

Comment: "Undefined reference" is a linker error. Have you linked to the appropriate libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link against the soci library and the appropriate backend.  Add "-lsoci" to your linker command line.

Update:

Based on comments, you need to add:

```
-L/usr/local/lib -lsoci_core -lsoci_mysql
```

to your linker command line.

Comment: I just tried that and ld, which I believe is the linker complained:
"/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsoci"

Comment: Then use need to use the -L option to specify the directory that contains your soci library (eg. libsoci.a)

Comment: Both libsoci_core.a and libsoci_mysql.a are in /usr/local/lib/, which seems like a pretty standard place for the linker to check without specifying. I used -L/usr/local/lib/ anyways, but I still got the error.

Comment: Also added -ldl to fix an error about shared object. Combined with janm's answer this fixes the problem.